# Python: Asyncio object-oriented style

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

I'm seeking a review of some code I've written for a small personal project. The project is not yet mature enough for any domain specific details to be of concern - but I'm happy to provide further details/examples should this help the review.

A description of what I hope to achieve and minimal working example has been provided below to help guide the review.

Comments relating to my use of the [Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library would be very much appreciated, as this is an area that is quite new to me, and I was not able to find any examples implemented in an OOP style.

**Concise problem statement**

> In a sentence, the `Limiter` class code should provide an extensible way to **restrict the rate at which certain functions can be invoked.**
>
> For this example, I have tried to limit the invocation of `increment()` to 5 calls every 10 seconds.
>
> It is important that this limit is imposed asynchronously so that other computations can be performed in the background. For this example, simply display the count.
>
> I have tried to maintain an OOP style interface.

**Minimal working example**

**Limiter**

```
class Limiter(object):

    """

    The purpose of this class is to limit the invocation of increment()
    based on a evaluation of 'some_condition' wrt. the class's internal state.

    """

    def __init__(self: object) -> None:
        self.counter, self.limit = 0, 5

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.schedule_tasks()

    def schedule_tasks(self: object) -> None:
        """ Minimal selection of tasks for this demonstation. """

        self.loop.create_task(self.reset_counter())
        self.loop.create_task(self.display())

    def _increment(self: object) -> None:
        """ Increment counter variable. """

        print('Incrementing counter')
        self.counter += 1

    async def reset_counter(self: object) -> None:
        """ Periodically (10s) reset the counter value. """

        while True:
            print('Resetting Counter')
            self.counter = 0
            await asyncio.sleep(10)

    async def display(self: object) -> None:
        """ Periodically (1s) display the counter value. """

        while True:
            print(self.counter)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def increment(self: object) -> bool:
        """ Provided that some_condition is met, call increment(). """

        some_condition = (self.counter < 5)

        if (some_condition):
            self._increment()
            return True

        print('some_condition not met - Not able to call increment().')
        return False
```

**Caller**

```
class Caller(object):

    """

    An object interfacing with the limiter.

    Periodicalyl call limiter.increment()
    Calls to increment() should be restricted by the limiter based
    on the evaluation of 'some_condition' wrt the limiters internal state.

    """

    def __init__(self: object) -> None:
        self.limiter = Limiter()

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.schedule_tasks()

    def schedule_tasks(self: object) -> None:
        """ Minimal selection of tasks for this demonstation. """

        self.loop.create_task(self.make_call())

    async def make_call(self: object) -> None:
        """ Periodically (1s) call increment. """

        while True:
            await self.limiter.increment()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```
def main():

    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        caller = Caller()
        loop.run_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopping event loop')
        loop.stop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example console output**

> ```
> Hodgson:Limiter hodgson$ python main.py 
> Resetting Counter
> Counter: 0
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 1
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 2
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 3
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 4
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 5
> some_condition not met - Not able to call increment().
> Counter: 5
> some_condition not met - Not able to call increment().
> Counter: 5
> some_condition not met - Not able to call increment().
> Counter: 5
> some_condition not met - Not able to call increment().
> Counter: 5
> some_condition not met - Not able to call increment().
> Resetting Counter
> Counter: 0
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 1
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 2
> Incrementing counter
> Counter: 3
> Incrementing counter
> ^CStopping event loop
> ```

**The code can also be found here: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BiodegradableKookyDeletion)**

I am using Python v3.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Old style declaration

```
class Limiter(object):
    ...
```

Using `object` as a base class is no longer necessary.  Simply write:

```
class Limiter:
    ...
```

Same for the other classes

## Wrong receiver type-hint

```
    def __init__(self: object) -> None:
        ...
```

`self` is not any `object`; it must be a `Limiter` (or class derived from `Limiter`).  The proper type-hint to use would be `Limiter`, but that type is still being defined so you can’t use it directly.  The type-hint `”Limiter”` would be possible to use.  However, any type-checker knows that the `self` argument must be of the type of the class.  It should be left implicit:

```
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...
```

Same for the other methods.

## Synchronous Async method

```
    async def increment(self: object) -> bool:
        ...
```

This method doesn’t await any results.  It does not need to be `async`.

```
    def increment(self) -> bool:
        ...
```

## PEP-8

```
    if (some_condition):
        ...
```

Conditionals do not need to be enclosed in `(...)`’s.

Methods which are for internal usage only should be marked as “private” (leading underscore).  These include `schedule_tasks`, `reset_counter`, `display`, and `make_call`.

Similarly, non-public data members should have an leading underscore: `limiter`, `loop`, `limit` and `count`.